# Calculate width & height of the selected text (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I need to calculate the `width` and the `height` of the selected/highlighted text using JavaScript.

I am using the following code written by Tim Down, as the starting point,

```
function getSelectionCoords() {
    var sel = document.selection, range;
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    if (sel) {
        if (sel.type != "Control") {
            range = sel.createRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            x = range.boundingLeft;
            y = range.boundingTop;
        }
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            if (range.getClientRects) {
                range.collapse(true);
                var rect = range.getClientRects()[0];
                x = rect.left;
                y = rect.top;
            }
        }
    }
    return { x: x, y: y };
}
```

The `left` & the `top` co-ordinates are being displayed correctly. To calculate the width & the height, I need the `right` & the `bottom` positions as well.

So I added few lines of code to find the `bottom` & the `right` positions (Code available here - http://jsfiddle.net/pankajparashar/kv2Bp/). But to my surprise, the code displays the `left` & the `right` co-ordinates always the same, even though there is visible difference between them (tested only in firefox).

There is no problem with the `top` & the `bottom` positions, as they are working perfectly, which will help me calculate the height. But to calculate the width, I would still need the correct `right` co-ordinate.

Can anybody point any flaws with the code? or any alternate approach, using which I can calculate the width & the height of the selected text?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's some code to get the dimensions of the selection's bounding rectangle. It's pretty similar to the original code.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UFkjy/

```
function getSelectionDimensions() {
    var sel = document.selection, range;
    var width = 0, height = 0;
    if (sel) {
        if (sel.type != "Control") {
            range = sel.createRange();
            width = range.boundingWidth;
            height = range.boundingHeight;
        }
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            if (range.getBoundingClientRect) {
                var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
                width = rect.right - rect.left;
                height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
            }
        }
    }
    return { width: width , height: height };
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Exactly, what i was looking for! Also works in Internet Explorer as well.

Comment: I realize this is an older thread - but looking at the Fiddle, the height number is inaccurate when crossing <p> elements. If all the text is within a single <p> element it's accurate, but not when crossing <p> elements.

Comment: @Wes: You're right, in Chrome, at least. Firefox is OK, Safari 7.1 is OK. I suspect a browser bug in Chrome.

Comment: @TimDown it looks like you're correct. I've submitted a bug to the Google Chrome team. Hopefully they'll fix it, though probably not likely any time soon.

Comment: While not a beautiful solution and not supported everywhere, I've found that this can be addressed by checking navigator.userAgent to see if it's a Chrome browser, and then using getClientRecs() to calculate the correct height by multiplying the height of the first line by 1.55 * the number of rectangles (1.55 being the average difference between height on FireFox/Safari and Chrome). The results are extremely close and could work as a stop-gap measure until Google fixes this issue. I can post as a possible revision if you like. You can see it in action here http://jsfiddle.net/u4sge0k3/

Comment: This doen't work with rich text though! http://jsfiddle.net/mayankcpdixit/u4sge0k3/1/

Comment: @mayankcpdixit: I just tried it in Chrome and Firefox. It should work fine for rich text and does in Firefox but it looks like Chrome has some issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try using *range.getBoundingClientRect* instead of *range.getClientRects*.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kv2Bp/4/)

Comment: Good. For some reason, it is not working in IE8, though it is working in firefox.

Comment: Fiddle results in `404`