# Is there a way to get the width of a Selection/Range?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, selection

You can get the current `Selection` with `getSelection()` and its `Range` with `getRangeAt(0)`. There's a bunch of information in there: starting node, ending node, characters, position etc.

What's not in there are the dimensions of the selection.

What I could do (I think, I haven't tried, because it's complex), is get the selected text, put it into the containing element, make the element inline and measure its width (and then undo all that to not mess up the DOM). Maybe.

But there must be an easier way.

It doesn't have to work with a selection over several elements, but it should work over several lines.

Maybe there's a trick to make a screenshot and measure pixels by color?

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right track there. Why not create a new div, fill it with just the selection, match the formatting, measure it, then make it go away again?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12603796/96100

Comment: `range.getClientRects()`! YES! That's what I meant! @TimDown Did you find that on SO after reading this or did you already know that one? I couldn't find it...

Comment: @Rudie: I remembered answering a similar question before.

Comment: @TimDown What do I do with this question? Apparently it was a duplicate and the only answer isn't good enough. I don't want to leave it open, unanswered.

Comment: @Rudie: Problem seems to be solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a selection of elements on a page?

You could enumerate the elements you've selected, get the left, right, top, and bottom borders for each one.

Then, find the maximum right and bottom borders and the minimum left and bottom borders and find the difference.

Comment: What if there's only 1 element?