# Jquery drag drop on html canvas

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

Hello I am trying to drag itms from a div ( li items) onto a html canvas. I have an issue with helper clone.

When i simply drag items without helper, it drop itms onto canvas, but when i use helper clone it does not drop items onto canvas. I have attached a fiddle please check it.

HTML

```
<ul id="drag">
    <li class="new-item">Drag me down1</li>
    <li class="new-item">Drag me down2</li>
    <li class="new-item">Drag me down3</li>
</ul>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

JS

```
$("#drag li").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
});
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/knawaz771/vDXQL/2/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you drop, do you want the helper to be positioned over the canvas element (the helper element would not become part of the canvas element itself) or do you want the same text that's in the helper to be drawn on the canvas itself (the text would become pixels on the canvas)?

Comment: Mark,You got it right, yes i want to make that part of canvas, whether it is a simple text or any other html element, I just want to drop it on on canvas and it should become part of canvas so that i can take copy of the canvas image containing all droped texts/elements/images, hope i made it clear

Answer (score 6):

If you want to print that text on canvas, you need to use jQuery droppable method,

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/6WpKf/)

```
$("#myCanvas").droppable({
    accept: "li",
    drop: function(event,ui){
        var context = $(this)[0].getContext("2d");
        context.font = "16px helvetica";
        context.fillText($(ui.draggable).clone().text(),ui.position.left - event.target.offsetLeft,ui.position.top - event.target.offsetTop);
    }
});
```

Comment: +1  Looks close.  You might adjust the drop Y-position for the height of the text. An approximate is 3/4 of 16px.  A more accurate measure can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603397/calculate-width-height-of-the-selected-text-javascript

Comment: @ranganadh But now how would you drag the text out of the box now, and have said line disappear from the canvas when you do?

Comment: When text is drawn on canvas, only pixel data from 0 - 255 will be present in canvas, we can't drag text (which was print on canvas) out of canvas.