# Width of selected text - jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the width of a selected text in pixels and show it as an `alert();`. Does this exist?

EDIT (copied it from the comment I wrote below)

I did many efforts but all went in vain, now i'm trying to see if I can get the value of `selection.toString()` and then bind it to `.width()` if i can manage to do it, i'm pretty sure i can combine them both to get the width I'm looking for.

EDIT 12:42 am

I tried this

```
if(selection.toString() != '' ){
    var selected = selection.toString();
    alert($(selected).width());
}
```

I get the value of `null`

Comment: `$('p').width()` ????

Comment: @BhojendraNepal - Not quite.  The OP wants the width of just the _selected_ portion of text, not all the text in the element.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes - this seems like a pretty straightforward question. I think the answer is basically "no", though.

Comment: close vote is because that OP didn't show his effort (at least he should show us a code that he tried so far)

Comment: @ChrisMartin - It's doubtful a prebuilt library exists for this, I agree.  However in the simple case it should be possible to get the selected text, clone the containing element's styles onto a placeholder element, write the text into the placeholder, and then measure the width of the placeholder element.  Complications may occur if the selected text actually spans multiple elements; in that case it may be reasonable to return the width of the containing element, or the `body` element, or something similar.

Comment: What code would one possibly "try so far"? There is no starting point for this. Either a browser supports it simply, or the solution is hideously complicated and OP probably shouldn't try to write it themselves.

Comment: @aroth It's also quite difficult if the selection is line-wrapped.

Comment: @ChrisMartin: There is not even a single question in the universe that can not be answered. :) Answers are always there, they may not be straightforward, but there cannot be 'no answer` :D #PhilosophicalThursday

Comment: @AdityaParab https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GYuBv/364/

Comment: I did many efforts but all went in vain, now i'm trying to see if I can get the value of `selection.toString()` and then bind it to `.width()`
if i can manage to do it, i'm pretty sure i can combine them both to get the width I'm looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate width & height of the selected text (javascript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603397/calculate-width-height-of-the-selected-text-javascript)

Comment: @ChrisMartin : Cood one :D They will be answered too, in due time. Besides, that's a `Theorem`. Not all theorems are facts. :D But I like your presence of mind. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I found out what i was looking for, code seems a bit basic since i'm new to jquery

```
 $(function(){
        $(document.body).bind('mouseup', function(e){
            var selection;


            if (window.getSelection) {
              selection = window.getSelection();
            } 

            if(selection.toString() != '' ){
                 $(".position").show();
                var select = selection.toString() ; 
               //some code
                $(".hiden").html(select);
                var width = $(".hiden").width();
                var height = $(".hiden").height();
            }
```

I used the value i get into the `var select`and added it to a hidden span into my html code, then i calculated its width and tried even with the height and worked.

thank you for u help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you mean by `selected` text as the `highlighted text` here is what you can do. A dirty way but then again for a dirty task :D

You can get highlighted text by (this won't work for IE)

`var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();`

And then create a hypothetical element `z` (becuase you don't know whatstyles are applied to the standard html elements. Let's call this element `z`.

So you get,

```
var el = $('<z/>',text:selectedText,id:'hahaha').appendTo('body').css('display','none');

alert(el.width());

el.remove();
```

We append it to the body and make it invisible so that it won't alter your view. And once you get the width, we remove it. Simple. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UFkjy/)

JS:

```
function getSelectionDimensions() {
    var sel = document.selection, range;
    var width = 0, height = 0;
    if (sel) {
        if (sel.type != "Control") {
            range = sel.createRange();
            width = range.boundingWidth;
            height = range.boundingHeight;
        }
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            if (range.getBoundingClientRect) {
                var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
                width = rect.right - rect.left;
                height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
            }
        }
    }
    return { width: width , height: height };
}
```

REFRENCE [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603397/calculate-width-height-of-the-selected-text-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If the element has no fixed width but is contained dynamically this might work for you?

```
<p id="random">testing</p>

var elem   = document.getElementById('random');
var height = elem.offsetHeight;
var width  = elem.offsetWidth;

alert(height + ' x ' + width);
```

offsetHeight will work but offsetWidth will give you the width of whatever container it's in, so if it's dynamically sized in its own element you should be able to get the accurate width.